# Strong induction inequality proof using floor

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

My professor showed this inequality to class today and I've been having a tough time trying to solve it. I know that I have to use strong induction but don't know how to progress farther than the 2 base cases(n=1, n=2).

Recurrence relation: $$F(i) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & i \leq 2\\
3 F(\lfloor\frac{i}{3}\rfloor) + 5i, & i > 2
\end{cases}$$

To prove: $ F(n) \leq 4n \cdot log_{2}(n) +1 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the induction step assume that F(n) ≤ 4n·log<sub>2</sub>(n)+1 for n∈ℕ.
Then, we get for k∈{0,1,2}:
F(3n+k) = 3F(⌊<sup>3n+k</sup>/<sub>3</sub>⌋)+5(3n+k) = 3F(n)+5(3n+k) ≤ 3(4n·log<sub>2</sub>(n)+1)+5(3n+k) = 12n·log<sub>2</sub>(n)+3+5(3n+k) ≤ 12n·log<sub>2</sub>(n)+6(3n+k) < 4(3n+k)·log<sub>2</sub>(n)+4(3n+k)·log<sub>2</sub>(3) = 4(3n+k)·log<sub>2</sub>(3n) < 4(3n+k)·log<sub>2</sub>(3n+k)+1
And this is everything we had to prove.
To the second equal sign:
We have k∈{0,1,2} such that <sup>k</sup>/<sub>3</sub> < 1. So we get
n ≤  n+<sup>k</sup>/<sub>3</sub> < n+1
And (because n is a natural number) this inequality leads to
⌊n+<sup>k</sup>/<sub>3</sub>⌋ = n
And this results in
⌊<sup>3n+k</sup>/<sub>3</sub>⌋ = ⌊<sup>3n</sup>/<sub>3</sub>+<sup>k</sup>/<sub>3</sub>⌋ = ⌊n+<sup>k</sup>/<sub>3</sub>⌋ = n

Comment: After the second equal sign, you convert F(floor((3n+k)/3)) to just F(n). How exactly does this work? You'll have to forgive me if I'm missing something incredibly obvious, we haven't actually formally learned about floor function yet.

Comment: I added some information in the answer. So I hope it becomes more obvious now.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I bow down to your superior understanding of induction.